# react-native-navigation v2 (wix) showModal animation fade

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I'm currently working on a project in which we are trying to implement the wix/react-native-navigation **V2** instead of react-navigation.

We want similar behaviour as in Instagram.

We are setting *bottomTabs* on *setRoot* and thought about showing following screens as Modals with *Navigation.showModal*.

.

**Our Question**

Is there a way to change the fade-in animation of a Modal?

.

Do you have tips regarding this problem?

Is it better to use stacks where we can *push* other screens?

.

thanks for your help.

*bump*

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, didnt find any solution. Just switched to react navigation